# USB Keyboard barcode scanner inputs wrong digits only in OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard, usb, scanning

I'm having a bit of a weird issue with my barcode scanner under OSX (El Capitan). It's a generic barcode scanner, Proster branding, with a Megawin USB-UART chip inside so it acts as a USB Keyboard.

When I try and use it in OSX to enter a barcode into TextWrangler for instance, it inputs digits OK, but they are all wrong - the barcode entered is nothing like the barcode scanned. Using the scanner in Windows, the barcode is entered fine.

I've tried putting the device into serial mode (it doesn't show up in OSX), tried changing keyboard layout in the detection wizard, and fiddling with some of the other settings, but no success. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd try serial mode again - do you have proper drivers installed?

Comment: There were no drivers provided, nor a link where to get them. If you can find some, I'll give them a go! What's weird is the USB mode - why would it work fine in Windows yet in OSX the barcode digits are completely wrong?

Comment: I should add I tried the Serial app I saw in another thread on here, which purports to have a bunch of serial drivers inbuilt. It didn't pick up the scanner in serial mode.

Comment: Check that the scanner doesn't have proprietary serial drivers. If it doesn't, I've found that the FTDI chipset is most common, you may try the instructions [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ftdi-drivers/mac) to just test if the scanner is in fact reporting the correct values to the mac.